# mapStateToProps not getting called after state change in Reducer

Tags: react-native, redux, state

I have a simple SignUp Form. the files i have are signup.js, authActions.js and signUpReducer.js.
When an action is performed the actions creator dispatches an action and reducer receives the action object and also updates the state but the component props are not being updated as expected.

```js
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) =>
{ 
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case USER_PHONECHANGE: 
            return { ...state, phone: action.payload };  

        case USER_EMAILCHANGE:  
            return { ...state , email : action.payload };  

        case USER_FIRSTNAMECHANGE:
            return { ...state, fName: action.payload };

        case USER_MIDDLENAMECHANGE:
            return { ...state, mName: action.payload };

        case USER_LASTNAMECHANGE:
            return { ...state, lName: action.payload };

        case USER_GENDERCHANGE:
            return { ...state, gender: action.payload };

        case USER_SIGNUP_SUCCESS:
            return state;

        case USER_SIGNUP_FAIL:
            return state;

        default: 
            return state;
    }
};
```

```js
const mapStateToProps = state =>
{   
    console.log("hited");
    return { userData : state.signUp };
       
};

const mapDispatchToProps =  {UserPhoneNoChanged, UserEmailChanged, UserFirstNameChanged, UserMiddleNameChanged, UserLastNameChanged, UserGenderChanged,UserSignUp}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignUp);
```

Comment: Did you double check if there's a mistake in your types??

Comment: Can you provide more code? What do your actions look like? Where are your action types declared?

Comment: @Perniferous the types are pretty straight forward i have checked them multiple time.everything is working fine just mapStateToProps does not get hit on state update

Comment: @JacobBralish ... here are the authactions code:export const UserPhoneNoChanged = (text) =>
{ 
    return {
        type: USER_PHONECHANGE,
        payload: text
    }
}

export const UserEmailChanged = (text) =>
{ 
    
    return {
        type: USER_EMAILCHANGE,
        payload: text
    }
}
{
    return {
        type: USER_LASTNAMECHANGE,
        payload: text
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

mapStateToProps will not be called when USER_SIGNUP_SUCCESS or USER_SIGNUP_FAIL is dispatched since you aren't changing the state in those cases. If you really need `mapStateToProps()` to be called after those actions have hit the reducer you need to change the state before returning it:

```js
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => { 

  switch(action.type) {

    case USER_SIGNUP_SUCCESS:
      return {...state}; // now the state has another reference 

    case USER_SIGNUP_FAIL:
      return {...state}; // now the state has another reference 

    default: 
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: it was not intented to invoke mapStateToProps() on SignUP_Success Or SignUp_Fail but on the change of form elements like email and phone. in those cases i am returning a new object of state that should invoke the mapStateToProps() but it is not ....